Unity: Project acts different after installing to android
I’ve been working on my google vr project using Unity 2019.4.40f1. The apk acts strangely compared to testing it in the Editor. I’m a complete beginner and lacks knowledge and experience so if I’m missing steps, i would appreciate to get some tips and help.
[context]
editor sample vid
apk sample vid
The first bug that i observed is the ui buttons, the google vr reticle sometimes doesn’t accurately interact with the buttons (as you can see the reticle supposedly transforms from a dot to a circle whenever pointed to interactable objects such as buttons and objects with event trigger) in the video context, the reticle sometimes triggers even if I’m outside the button and sometimes, the reticle doesn’t trigger even if its aiming to the button.
The ui buttons in the android build works like this:
Context
(red ink is where the reticle triggers)
secondly, after pressing the ui button named restart with scene manager loadscene attached to them, the scene doesn’t reload properly, the current scene reloads but the camera is off, its like you’re in edit scene mode inside the editor, the camera stays still in one place and angle while the “player” object moves (see in video). The scenemanager script is inside an empty game object.
for additional information, I’m using IL2CCP and not Mono because I’m testing the project on a android 14 OS and i suppose it requires ARM64 architecture. i don’t know if these causes the scene load bug or not.
I hope someone can help me with this especially the UI button part.
Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
